# How can I maintain stable/smooth performance permanently on a Nexus 7 2012 (wifi) [grouper/nakasi]?

Tags: nexus-7, reboot, performance, user-interface

After a day to a few days, the n7's performance will degrade sharply to the point where a reboot is necessary for the device to function properly.

I've tried numerous ROMs, a few kernels, tweaking CPU governors (mainly just to performance) yet no matter what I try it will work great for a while but if I let it sit idle for a day or so load times for doing anything jump up to unacceptably slow levels.

By unacceptably slow I mean on the order of magnitude of 10 times longer than normal or more. UI elements and the UI itself are often unresponsive to very slow and even when it catches up to the first command (ie home button), the next command still takes just as long (ie loading an app).

This is a single user device and has very few apps and fewer running. There is always lots of free ram usually 50% or so.

Right now it's running lollipop (ART) but no difference.

Is there something I can do so I don't *have* to reboot every day?

How can I diagnose what component(s) specifically need the reboot to begin functioning normally again?

Comment: When you say degraded performance, what is your base for measure? I have MultiRom on my Nexus 7 Grouper, with 5 different ROMs (varying from JB to Lollipop) and I haven't noticed any performance issues. Have you looked at what background services and broadcast receivers are running? Also, what what apps do you have installed? Maybe an app with wish-washy permissions.

Comment: Also ART has been known to have performance/compatability issues as well. There are some ROMs that will work with ART, but that would be a matter of reading some forums. I use Dalvik because of smooth compatibility. :)

Comment: That bodes well. My base for measure is a fairly smooth and responsive UI where it only takes a second or so to do something like go home, open the recent apps screen, or load an app instead of 7-10+ seconds. Have you left a few of those ROMs totally idle for a few days? It may actually be more like 3 days when it starts to suffer. I haven't looked closely just enough to see that only what I would expect to be running is running. I am essentially running pure android + google. Even running totally stock from a factory reset I still saw the same degradation.

Comment: So I don't think it's an app-related problem but something between the OS/hardware level. It runs the same on Dalvik as it does with ART.

Comment: This is a good write-up: http://androidandme.com/2013/06/opinions/one-year-later-the-nexus-7-has-gone-from-the-best-to-worst-tablet-ive-ever-owned/

Comment: May have found the culprit: https://gigaom.com/2013/07/30/got-a-laggy-old-nexus-7-heres-why-android-4-3-will-restore-its-performance/ - notably: *Klug says the TRIM command is automatically invoked every 24 hours or so on the Nexus 7 with Android 4.3. It happens when the device is active but not used for an hour during one day’s time and has either 80 percent battery life or is being charged and has at least 30 percent battery life. The maintenance is automatic then, so there’s no user action required.* - It's often unplugged and not above 80%

Comment: On all my ROMs, I leave the tablet on for multiple days before switching back and forth. I haven't used 4.3 at all,  just didn't like it on any device. Good reading on that "androidandme" link. Have you tried any other versions besides 4.3?

Comment: Well I read a number of reports on TRIM and the general consensus on the performance issues that happen. Fragmentation of files, just like on the PC, is what is the culprit. TRIM will actually take a long time to "defragment" your files,  an easier idea would be to back up your data and perform a factory reset or better yet do a complete wipe of the system, then flash your ROM. Almost all the reading said there would be problems if the system wasn't properly "formatted" (no prior files still floating around), prior to the installation of 4.3.

Comment: Here are 2 links with excellent info on this [1)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/nexus-storage-performance-time-trim-t1971852#fm) and [2)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1929021#fm)

Comment: I think I may have jumped straight to 4.4 from day one and after that I've been on 5.0+ since it was released officially. I have done several FDRs as well as complete manual wipes, re-installs via TWRP. This link (http://goo.gl/cu8wAo) has a noteworthy remark: *However, this update does nothing to fix existing sectors that should have been TRIMMed in the past, but were not. To do this yourself, you can try the LagFix app from Google Play (it requires root). This app is a frontend to the fstrim utility, and it will TRIM your empty storage, fixing this problem.* - I'll give this a try.

Comment: On the TRIM script there is a bug/problem, so there is a fix on the link I posted for the script. As usual read everything.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up auto fstrim with [Device Control [root]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.namelessrom.devicecontrol&hl=en) and after a few weeks have not seen the same degradation I was seeing before. I am running CM12 lollipop nightlies.

You can set it up in *Extras* >*Filesystem* :

[image]

Comment: How is it still running after having it set up the auto fstrim?

Comment: Should it not be?

Comment: No, is it still working great or has there been any hang ups since them? So its a long term fix? I just wanted to know as far as a follow up. I have 2 N7's.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN: Been running solid since - highly recommended. You'll maybe still get a slight, and I mean slight, initial lag when first touching the thing but it is miles better overall.